# xcode crashed and project not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode

I am doing a project and till morning it works properly and i do some changes while i changing,then Xcode crashed and project automatically saved and i want to recover my project whose work properly in morning.

Is any way to recover my right project because it is not save any where.

Comment: you can't recover once it is quit.

Comment: It means no way to recover my project

Comment: whenever you create a project it asks first for saving location them you can work on that?

Comment: you dont know where you saved your project?

Comment: I know but working project not work properly now.